# Voice recordering in Android web view app using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to open my web page as Android app. I want to add voice recording functionality using phone microphone in my web app. When a link on web app page is clicked it should start recording and save the recorded file.

After searching its possibility, i came up with "Cordova". But still not able to make it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution for this issue. Web page can be opened in an iFrame and then it can communicate with the app.
Refer example below for using Camera of the device.

[[http://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/][1]](http://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/getting-access-to-a-phones-camera-from-a-web-page/%5d%5b1%5d)

It works...:)